# vs code self closing tag issue for <input>

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, input

Input (<input>) doesn't have a self-closing tag, but in vs. code, when I save the code, it adds the closing tag automatically.

```html
<label for=""><input type="" name="" id="" />A</label>
```

Visual Studio Code adds the closing tag but it's not correct for the input and adding the closing tag when I save it. is there any solution for this?

When I write the code it,

> ```
> <input type="" name="" id="">
> ```

But when I save it on vs. code, it becomes

> ```
> <input type="" name="" id=""/>
> ```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in a new document using the `Format Document` command. Do you have a formatter extension like prettier active? If so, produce a [mre] with the config for the [mre]. Note: [related MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#self-closing_tags)